# JavaScript code execution sequence for callback and contradictions to normal execution sequence

Tags: javascript, callback

I can't seem to reconcile the technical flow of javascript execution sequence and the concept of callbacks.  I have been using callbacks, but I am not happy with the execution flow because it appears that there are contradictions between idea of callback and the sequential JavaScript execution.  This link http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/ explains callback and give examples, but I as I follow the code, I see a contradiction.

```
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', writeData);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "show this before data ...";

function getData(dataURI, callback) {
    var myData = getSomeData(); // fake function
    callback(myData);
}

function writeData(myData) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += myData;
}
```

My question/observation is that inside the function `getData`, the `callback(myData)` statement does not get executed until after the function `getSomeData()` is finished and returned a value to the variable `myData`, but then the contradiction occurs when the `document.getElementById...` statement is allowed to execute before the `getData` function call is finished executing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `document.getElementById` cannot be executed before `getData` gets completely executed, unless `getData` is async. (Which by seeing there's a URL passing to `getData` tells me you are doing an AJAX which is async)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` cannot be executed before `getData` gets completely executed, unless `getData` is asynchronous. By seeing there's a URL passing to `getData` tells me you are doing AJAX which is asynchronous.

Although your code won't behave like you said (it's synchronous!) because `var myData = getSomeData()` is synchronous, pretending the whole `getData` function is async and the flow goes like this:

1. Executes `getData`.
2. `getData` does its internal stuff and returns `undefined`.
3. Proceeds to `document.getElementById`.
4. Later `getData` gets its data and the browser or other environment executes the callback function passed to it before.
5. Executes statements inside `writeData`.

There are many ways that can create an async function, such as [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), and other [timers](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) (`setTimeout/Interval`).

Comment: Derek, I agree with your explanation.  That is the source of my question. Assume that the 'getSomeData' function is an async API call, how would the statements below it know whether to wait or go ahead and execute?  Likewise for the document.getElementById, how would it know if the 'getData' is an async?

Comment: @Jamex well asynchronous simply means setting up a "timer" or something similar and the browser (or other environment) will execute some function you defined at some later point for you. The asynchronous part is only talking about the callback function, not the setting-up-the-timer part which is synchronous.

Comment: I understand async, but I guess it is not obvious to me how javascript can tell which statement is async and which is sync.  Is it because setTimeOut or AJAX calls automatically notify the javascript engine that they are Async?

Comment: They don't notify the engine that they are async, actually they are implemented async right in the engine itself. Every async function is a native function, and they can also make your callbacks not async (such as XMLHttpRequest which can be set to synchronous although not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

#### Synchronous vs. Asynchronous Execution

I think you're getting those two things mixed up.  I'll quote and correct you below:

> the `callback(myData)` statement does not get executed until after the function `getSomeData()`

**Correct.**  This is ***synchronous*** (line-by-line) execution.

> the `document.getElementById...` statement is allowed to execute before the `getData` function call is finished executing.

**Incorrect.**  Again, this is synchronous execution - `'show this before...'` will be inserted *after* the data.

You're likely thinking about callbacks in the context of ***asynchronous*** execution.  Compare your synchronous code to this asynchronous version, which *does* insert `'show this ...'` before the contents of `myData`:

```
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', writeData);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "show this before data ...";

function getData(dataURI, callback) {
    //var myData = getSomeData();
    //callback(myData);
    getSomeDataAsync(callback);
}

function writeData(myData) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += myData;
}
```

The change is in the `getData` function.  `callback` is *passed as an argument, rather than called immediately with the `()` operator*.

The `getSomeDataAsync` function is asynchronous, meaning it will pop itself in the run loop's "background" before executing your `myData` callback.  It won't run your callback until the event it is waiting for fires (i.e. when data retrieval completes).  While `getSomeDataAsync` is waiting, execution resumes on the code that called it, which will insert your `'show this before...'` immediately.

When the completion event fires, execution will resume, and the passed `callback` parameter will be executed.  The contents of `myData` will then be appended!

[Check out this fiddle to see what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/4x3rp/)

Comment: kdbanman, thanks for the explanation.  The source of my confusion is how would one statement know whether the statement preceding it is an async?

Comment: BTW, I made an update to your jsfiddle to clearer demonstrate the async results. http://jsfiddle.net/4x3rp/1/

Comment: That modification does make things clearer, thanks.  And none of the statements know whether or not any other statement is async or not.  A function that *waits* for many cycles, like a read, write, or network action, will make the entire program wait if it is synchronous.  If the function async, then the program can continue execution while the function waits.  One of the things to remember about async programming is that *you can't necessarily know at what point in the execution an async function will actually finish.*  Hope that helps.